# domain controller naming group policy

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, group-policy, best-practices

i have two domain controller setup one on 192.168.1.10 companyname.local and 192.168.1.20 companyname.local as backup. i was task of rebuilding the backup and make it the main domain controller. i took the backup offline and rebuilt it should i change the name from companyname.local to ad.companyname.com. this is with server 2012 this is only hosting dns active directory no dhcp. small group 10 users.

also i was testing group policy add network drive. it works the user logins add drive b: but when the user log off and new user login with different drive f: it doest remove the other user drive  b: show both drive. this test was done on the same computer with different user login.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , ideally about a single [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) issue  and contains sufficient details to provide you with a good solution. - Please edit and improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved.

Answer (score 2):

.local domain names are bad news. Many moons ago it was a best practice but it no longer is a good idea. I help run an Active directory infrastructure for a large corporation and we have a .local domain. It causes problems and is annoying but at the end of the day everything works.

Would I recommend trying to move everything to a new domain? No. Not unless you have a rationale as to why. You will have to create a new forest and basically rebuild the domain from scratch.

This article is useful for explaining the problem with local domains:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200810122929/http://www.mdmarra.com/2012/11/why-you-shouldnt-use-local-in-your.html

As to creating a shared drive I would recommend you create a batch file user logon script. The file would have a command like net use z: \server\share and you would get a consistent letter.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJJrN4BoGpM

Comment: rebuilding because the main server got corrupted by a virus and can't add computer to domain. and has a lot little glitches. i might do the batch file because the GPO seems a little glitchy i'm running 2012

Comment: I'll second the batch file - logon scripts offer instant gratification.  If you log on and have no drive, you know you did it wrong.  Group policy requires patience, of which I have some, the higher-ups little, and the end users none.  Best practices don't always give the best results in practice.